# Accessibility of YouTube live-streaming API

Tags: youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I am working on an Android project that needs to stream live video feed to YouTube. From the official YouTube data API 2.0:

```
Prerequisites

Please note the following prerequisites for using the API functionality described
in this section:

1. Developers need to sign an API Testing Agreement before their applications can
successfully issue requests to manage live events. Please contact the YouTube 
developer relations team via a post to the YouTube APIs Developer Forum if you 
are interested in incorporating this functionality into your application.

2. The ability to create, update, and delete live events is only available to some 
YouTube users. The Determining whether a user can create live events section 
explains how to check a user's profile entry to see whether a user has access 
to these features.
```

The Developer Forum mentioned above is closed already and stackflow is recommended instead, so I post my question here:

1. Where do I apply for the licence so that my Android application can successfully manage the live streaming?
2. How could I get an YouTube account that is live-streaming capable so I can test my application with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: [Livestreaming and API is available to all verified channels](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2013/12/3-2-1-and-you-are-live.html).

Livestreaming capabilities and API are only for selected partners for now. You can get more information on "http://www.youtube.com/yt/partners/"